# Proof by induction with three base cases (Isabelle)

Tags: isabelle, induction, isar

I want to be able to prove a statement by induction on n (of type nat). It consists of a conditional whose antecedent is only true for n >= 2. A conditional whose antecedent is false is always true. So I'd like to prove the cases n=0, n=1 and n=2 all separately from the main inductive step. Is it possible to do a proof by induction with *three* base cases like the following:

```
  lemma "P (n::nat) --> Q"
  proof (induct n)
    case 0
    show ?case sorry
  next
    case 1
    show ?case sorry
  next 
    case 2
    show ?case sorry
  next
    case (Suc n)
    show ?case sorry
  qed
```

As it stands, this doesn't seem to work. I could prove `"P (n+2) --> Q"` by induction instead, but it wouldn't be as strong a statement. I'm considering a case split into `"n=0"`,`"n=1"` and `"n>=2"`, and proving only the last case by induction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest way is probably to prove a custom induction rule for the kind of induction that you want, like this:

```
lemma nat_0_1_2_induct [case_names 0 1 2 step]:
  assumes "P 0" "P 1" "P 2" "⋀n. n ≥ 2 ⟹ P n ⟹ P (Suc n)"
  shows   "P n"
proof (induction n rule: less_induct)
  case (less n)
  show ?case using assms(4)[OF _ less.IH[of "n - 1"]]
    by (cases "n ≤ 2") (insert assms(1-3), auto simp: eval_nat_numeral le_Suc_eq)
qed

lemma "P (n::nat) ⟶ Q"
proof (induction n rule: nat_0_1_2_induct)
```

In theory, the `induction_schema` method is also very useful to prove such custom induction rules, but in this case, it doesn't help a lot:

```
lemma nat_0_1_2_induct [case_names 0 1 2 step]:
  "P 0 ⟹ P 1 ⟹ P 2 ⟹ (⋀n. n ≥ 2 ⟹ P n ⟹ P (Suc n)) ⟹ P n"
proof (induction_schema, goal_cases complete wf terminate)
  case (complete P n)
  thus ?case by (cases n) force+
next
  show "wf (Wellfounded.measure id)" by (rule wf_measure)
qed simp_all
```

You could also use `less_induct` directly and then do a case distinction within the induction step for the base cases.